# Win8 Delete Files on Device when Importing

Tags: windows-8, photos, import, windows-photo-gallery

Win8 has the native "Import Photos and Videos" app but also has a similar functionality in the WinRT environment in the Photos application.

The native application has an option to delete files on device after import.  This is a very handy feature which can help prevent importing the same files again leaving duplicate mess in the Photos file library.  No such setting that I can find exists on the WinRT "Photos" app.

I have configured my Win8 machine to open the "Import Photos and Videos" application when the camera is connected.  However, when connecting it the WinRT "Photos" app opens and not the native "Import Photos and Videos" app.

I either want to find a way for the WinRT "Photos" app to delete files after import OR have the native "Import Photos and Videos" application open upon connecting it to the computer.

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading.